# Regex Matching, when there is a pattern moving backward in the target String?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a file with each line having the following pattern:

```
A<space>B<space>C
```

where:

- A,B,C are three blocks of variable length Strings, for example "Hi I'm block A I'mB I'mC"
- B and C are each one word, C ends with line termination and there are "spaces" around B.
- A can pretty much be anything (can also have any variable number of spaces)

What regex pattern can I use to split the line in 3?!

I currently use something like: `substring(*line*.lastIndexOf(" "))` to get C, changing *line* to hold A B and repeat to get B, and then whatever is left is A.

But is there a way to do it with Regex?! In general how can Regex be used when the pattern is know moving backward in a string?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
^(.+?) (\S+) (\S+)$
```

[**Here's a demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qR8iL8/1). In your example, it captures three groups:

```
Hi I'm block A
I'mB
I'mC
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `(.+?)` capture any characters, but "non-greedy" (stop as soon as possible)
- a space
- `(\S+)` capture any group of non-whitespace characters
- a space
- `(\S+)` again, capture any group of non-whitespace characters
- `$` end of the line

Comment: yes Sir, exactly what I was looking for, simple and does the job, thanks (not enough reps to upvote)

Comment: @AmirGh Glad it helped! Please remember to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just do splitting on the `first` and `second space from last`.

```
string.split("\\s+(?=\\S+\\s+\\S+$)|\\s+(?=\\S+$)");
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/tI7pI5/1)